# How to get the current Azure FunctionNameAttribute?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

How do I access the function name set with `[FunctionName("SomeFunctionName")]` programmatically inside the function?

This is the function attribute name and not the method name.

eg: In the code below, I would like to do something like `if (!await PermissionsHelper.userHasPermission(getCurrentFunctionAttributeName(), TokenHelper.getTokenValue(req, "oid")))`

```
  public static class GetUser
  {
    [FunctionName("GetUser")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "users/{id}")]
          HttpRequest req,
          String id,
          ILogger log)
    {

      if (!await PermissionsHelper.userHasPermission("GetUser", TokenHelper.getTokenValue(req, "oid")))
        return new UnauthorizedResult();
```

Comment: you can get the FunctionName from ExecutionContext

Comment: @RomanKiss I'm new to c# can you provide a code sample? Also note that I'm not after method name, which is run in the above example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following:

```
public static class GetUser
{
  [FunctionName("GetUser")]
  public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "users/{id}")]
      HttpRequest req,
      String id,
      ExecutionContext executionContext,
      ILogger log)
  {

    if (!await PermissionsHelper.userHasPermission(executionContext.FunctionName, TokenHelper.getTokenValue(req, "oid")))
    return new UnauthorizedResult();
```